# Help wiring up DAC0800

Tags: 555, dac

I'm relatively new to electronics and have never used a DAC before. I have a [DAC0800](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac0800.pdf) and a [LF351N](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lf351.pdf) op-amp and have tried to set them up so that I can have a voltage output determined by the 8 digital inputs to the DAC.

My plan is to eventually connect the DAC inputs to the outputs of an EEPROM chip. The analog output of the DAC will then connect to the control pin of a 555 timer, to change its frequency.

To power it, I am using four 1.5V AA batteries in series to give 6V.

I was wondering whether anyone has any experience with this chip or circuit diagrams that could help me figure it out? It's the power that's the issue - the examples I can find usually use a dual rail supply of more than 6V, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Alternatively, is there an easier way of producing a square wave of digitally-controlled frequency, than using a DAC connected to a 555 timer?

Thank you!

Comment: _"is there an easier way of producing a square wave of digitally-controlled frequency, than using a DAC connected to a 555 timer?"_- what do you need this variable frequency square wave for, and what will be controlling it?

Comment: The signal will be connected to a speaker (through a capacitor) to produce different notes, so the frequency does not have to be exact. An EEPROM chip with an 8-bit output and address lines connected to a binary counter controls it.

Comment: Nice project, but it is very old-school and can be replaced by an MCU with built-in DAC and it will be more versatile. But it is easier, if not easiest way to do what you want, play tones with digitally controlled frequency, usually hardware timers can control DMA playback of PCM samples to a 12-bit DAC. You get even two channels stereo, and perhaps a megabyte of sample memory, and expandable via USB or SD memory cards.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I usually use microcontrollers but I wanted to try doing a project without one for a change to learn more about electronics, which is the reason for the old-school tech. It won't be very practically useful but I've had fun designing it.

Comment: For hobbyists, I usually recommend a cheapy MCP4725 module, (12 bit DAC with EEPROM). Feel free to ask @tlfong01 for more follow up newbie questions.

Comment: More references: (1) 
MCP4725 DAC Breakout Module Development Board 12Bit I2C IIC Interface Module - €1
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32294601702.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.2e962796PzatJx&algo_pvid=e124417b-e757-4db3-9da0-10d09c76b6c3&algo_expid=e124417b-e757-4db3-9da0-10d09c76b6c3-6&btsid=0bb0623216092061847698615e692f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

(2) MCP4725 SparkFun Tutorial 
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12918

Comment: MCP4725 is a popular DAC chip. You can also find good tutorials from AdaFruit. You can find loads of references, but usually for Arduino.  I have been playing it with Rpi4B. Let me know if you wish to know more about Rpi4B MCP4725 projects.

Comment: MCP4725 is actually 3 in 1: DAC, opAMP, and EEPROM, comparing with DAC0800, which is very old.

Comment: And you can easily google many voltage to frequency converters. Examples: (1) Voltage-to-Frequency Converters
https://www.analog.com/media/cn/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-028.pdf

(2) Two Simple Voltage to Frequency Converter
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/voltage-to-frequency-converter-circuit/. Have a nice project.  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, the MCP4725 looks like a nice chip. The only issue is that it uses an I2C interface, while I want an old-fashioned 8-bit input to make it easy to connect to an EEPROM. However, I just found the [AD558](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD558.pdf) which seems ideal for me. The voltage-to-frequency circuits you linked also look useful although a 555 timer seems to work well enough for now at the frequencies I want to generate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the DAC0800 specifies needing at least +/- 4.5V means that you will not be able to run this chip with a 6V source (at least not to spec). You can DC bias this part to "fake" a bipolar supply but you will need at least a 9V supply to have the headroom to swing.

If possible, try to stick to any of the manufacturer's reference designs as much as as you can (Figures 18 and on). These can be a good starting point for most designs.